# sine equation - signal processing

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-transform

I have a problem to solve in my signal processing course. The chapter of this question is "Sampling and aliasing".

Let's call $g_f(t) = \sin(2\pi.f.t) + \sin(2\pi.(f+\Delta_f).t) + \sin(2\pi.(f+2\Delta_f).t) + 2.\sin(2\pi.(f+3\Delta_f).t)$.

The first question was to visualize the frequency representation of $g_{1000}$.
The result was coherent : 4 negative Diracs in $f$, $f+\Delta_f$, $f+2\Delta_f$, $f+3\Delta_f$ and 4 positive Diracs in $-f$, $-f-\Delta_f$, $-f-2\Delta_f$, $-f-3\Delta_f$. Then I had to visualize the frequency representaion of $g_{2250}$. This time, the result was not according to theory because of aliasing ($2250 > \frac{f_e}{2}$, with $f_e$ the sempling frequency).
Here is the next question :

Find all the $f$ so $g_f(t)$ is equal to a unique sinus of another specific frequency.

Any idea about how to begin that ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f = -\Delta_f$.
We'll have,
$$g_f(t) = \sin(2\pi.-\Delta_f.t) + \sin(2\pi.(-\Delta_f+\Delta_f).t) + \sin(2\pi.(-\Delta_f+2\Delta_f).t) + 2.\sin(2\pi.(-\Delta_f+3\Delta_f).t)$$
So,
$$g_f(t) = \sin(2\pi.-\Delta_f.t) + \sin(2\pi.\Delta_f.t) + 2.\sin(2\pi.(2\Delta_f).t)$$

If we think in terms of frequency, the first sine has one negative Dirac peak in $-\Delta_f$ and one positive in $\Delta_f$.
The second one has one positive in $-\Delta_f$ and one negative in $\Delta_f$.
They cancel each other.

Finally it will only result 2 peaks, one positive in $-2\Delta_f$ and one negative in $2\Delta_f$ corresponding to the last sine.

So $g_{-\Delta_f.t}$ is equivalent to a unique sine of frequency $2\Delta_f$.